Selecting U edges on a polyPlane

I'm trying to select only the U edges on a poly plane and I can't find a sexy way to do it. I have tried selecting all the odd number edges.
poly_plane = cmds.polyPlane(name='ribbon_Geo', width=10, height=1, 
                            subdivisionsWidth=10, subdivisionsHeight=1)[0]
# Get the shape node
shape = cmds.listRelatives (polyPlane, shapes = True, type = "mesh")[0]

# Get the total number of edges
edge_count = cmds.polyEvaluate (shape, edge = True)

# Get all odd edges on the ribbon geometry
oddEdges = ["{}.e[{}]".format (shape, i) for i in range (edge_count) if i % 2 != 0]


This works ok. It selects all the edges I need but also selects some of the V direction edges that are odd numbered. So there is still some adjustment and I need to guess which edge is the end edge if its odd numbered.
I have tried using the polySelectConstraint command and that works well for the U edges. Does not select the end edges. I can append the first edge but don't know what the end edge is.
# Create the polyPlane
poly_plane = cmds.polyPlane(name='ribbon_Geo', width=10, height=1, 
                            subdivisionsWidth=10, subdivisionsHeight=1)[0]

# Get the shape node of the plane
shape = cmds.listRelatives(poly_plane, shapes=True, type="mesh")[0]

# Get the total number of edges
edge_count = cmds.polyEvaluate(shape, edge=True)

  
# Define the first and last edge
first_edge = cmds.ls(f"{shape}.e[0]")  # First edge
last_edge = cmds.ls(f"{shape}.e[{edge_count - 1}]")  # Last edge    
    
cmds.polySelectConstraint( mode = 3, type = 0x8000, angle = True, anglebound=(0, 89) )
polyConst = cmds.ls(selection = True)

allEdges = first_edge.append(polyConst)
cmds.select(allEdges)

Is there a better way to select the U edges of this poly plane?
This is part of much larger script and I need to be able to select these edges on any size plane with different number of edges. The plane may not always have 10 U edges it may have 3 or 5 or 35. I'm referring to the edges in the meddle of the plane not the border edges .

You might want tto poly select the ring of an edge and then isolate the loops so you can sort them out by uv if they have some (cmds.polyListComponentConversion)
or you can sort them out with the position xyz in the world. Then to select one over two, you can either way use this sorting or you can convert edge ring to vertex then back to edge and see how it connects to edges and order them that way to select sel[0::2]

bindJnt_hie = ['joint1', 'joint2', 'joint3']
bindJnt_count = 3 # number of joints in the chain.

# CREATE THE POLY PLANE WITH THE CALCULATED LENGTH
polyPlane = cmds.polyPlane (name ='ribbon_Geo', width = 10,
                                 height = 1, subdivisionsWidth = bindJnt_count, 
                                 subdivisionsHeight = 1)[0]

lastEdge = len(bindJnt_hie * 2)
endEdge = f"{polyPlane}.e[{lastEdge}]"
firstEdge = f"{polyPlane}.e[1]"
cmds.select (polyPlane)
cmds.polySelectConstraint (mode = 3, type = 0x8000, angle = True, anglebound = (0, 89))
midEdges = cmds.ls (selection = True)
cmds.polySelectConstraint (angle = False)
nestRib_Edges = [firstEdge, midEdges, endEdge]

# FLATTEN THE RIB EDGES LIST TO BE ABLE TO ITERATE THROUGH THEM
ribEdges = []
for item in nestRib_Edges:
    if isinstance (item, list):  # If the element is a list, extend the flattened list
        ribEdges.extend (item)
    else:  # Otherwise, append the individual item
        ribEdges.append (item)
        
print(ribEdges) 

This works perfectly for what I need. I figured out that the first edge will always be 1 and the last edge will always be the subdivision with * 2. The polySelectConstraint will select the middle edges that are 0 - 89 degrees. Now all I needed to do was put them in an array. Then I had to flatten the selection so I can be able to iterate through the array.
The end result should look like this:
print(ribEdges)        
['ribbon_Geo.e[1]', 'ribbon_Geo.e[3]', 'ribbon_Geo.e[5]', 'ribbon_Geo.e[6]']

This will allow me to use the edges to constrain or attach locators or joints to the ribbon geo.
